# How to create unstructured data in terraform

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to create configurations in terraform that I can later pass to modules (I'm doing this to work around the lack of "count" in modules).

The closest thing I got was using a `null_data_source` but the problem with that is that it only supports a single level of properties in inputs:

```
data "null_data_source" "my_data" {
    count = var.my_data_count
    inputs = {
        settings = { ... } //this doesn't work
    }
}
```

Then I looked at the docs of how to create a custom provider but couldn't work around the types that terraform supports - `TypeMap` will automatically turned into `map[string]string` unless I pass in the `Elem` property but that also only accepts terraform defined types (it doesn't accept standard golang types e.g.: `map[string]interface{}` or `interface{}`).

Does anyone know a way to get unstructured data as config like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "single level of properties"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "unstructured data" in Terraform: every value has an associated type. However, in Terraform 0.12 introduced two [structural types](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html#structural-types) that allow for different element/attribute types to be mixed together inside a single value, which is not possible for the collection types.

You can use [Local Values](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/locals.html) if you need to factor out the expressions for these structural values for use in multiple locations:

```
locals {
  your_data = {
    settings = {
      foo = "bar"
      baz = []
    }
  }
}
```

Although the details of this often don't matter, Terraform will see the above as being of the following type:

```
object({
  settings = object({
    foo = string
    baz = tuple([])
  })
})
```

As the author of a module, you can associated with each variable a [type constraint](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/types.html) that can both check that the given value has the appropriate type *and* give Terraform some hints to interpret such a value differently. For example, if `baz` in the above example were a list of strings whose length isn't fixed by the module (often the case) then you can specify it as such in your type constraint:

```
variable "example" {
  type = object({
    settings = object({
      foo = string
      baz = list(string)
    })
  })
}
```

Then the caller can pass in the local value we constructed earlier:

```
module "example" {
  source = "./modules/example"

  example = local.your_data
}
```

Terraform will then take the `tuple([])` value from the local value and convert it automatically to `list(string)`, in this case creating an empty list of strings.

---

For Terraform 0.11 your options are more limited, because it does not have structural types. In that case, the usual approach is to flatten the structure into many separate variables and set them separately, but then it's not possible to conveniently construct them all in one place and pass them as a single value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the in-depth answer!